# How can I rename a team project and area paths in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can I rename my Team Project that is hosted in Microsoft's Team Foundation Service? And how can I rename the area paths?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible in TFS 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, or 2013. However the work to complete this has been done and it is now available on VSO and will ship in TFS 2015.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/04/24/team-project-rename-available-on-vs-online.aspx

Comment: It is worth mentioning that "project areas" (or area paths, as they are called) can be edited. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181692.aspx.

Comment: they should have this in RED and BOLD :).. not gray and small-font.
**Note: You cannot change the name of your project after you have created it**

Comment: This is somewhat a flaw... i mean normally you should be able to rename anything you create. What a shame!

Comment: Looks like [**Team project rename**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037605-rename-project-in-tfs) is coming [**Q2 2015**](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso) to VSO, and then to TFS 2015 on-premise.

Answer (score 2):

You can now rename team projects in Visual Studio Online and the upcoming TFS 2015 release: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-apr-24-vso

Answer (score 0):

The [idea](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037605-rename-project-in-tfs) status changed to **STARTED**

Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded On Feb 27, 2015:

> Im am excited to announce that today we are planning to enable project
>   rename for TFS 2015. We don’t have an ETA yet for Visual Studio
>   Online.
>
> If you want to see our progress, visit the Future Feature Development
>   page at http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.
>
> Ewald Hofman TFS Program Manager