# Migrate TFS to new project name

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Why Must the project names be the same from the source TFS server as on the target TFS online?

We have a number of projects that we would like to rename.  Visual Studio online does not allow this to happen currently.   So it would be great if we could do this during the migration

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rename a team project and area paths in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344295/how-can-i-rename-a-team-project-and-area-paths-in-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

TFS doesn't allow you to rename projects either and they [don't seem to want to allow it](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037605-rename-project-in-tfs)!

The best "solution" offered by Microsoft is to create a new project with the desired name and branch your code into it. But then you also have to copy all work items across too, and when you delete the old project, you lose all history from before the branch.

So have you thought of voting with your feet and migrating to a system that works better?

Comment: Project rename is coming next year. See comments to this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/09/03/vs-amp-tfs-2013-update-4-ctp-1-is-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OVSMU is focused enabling migration from TFS to VSO and was not designed to support the rename use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can now rename team projects on Visual Studio Online and in the upcoming TFS 2015 release: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-apr-24-vso