# Error: The collection might have gone offline. You can refresh the page and we will try this again

Tags: tfs

While accessing some of the team projects in our collections. We suspect that, it might be due to Accents in the project names. If we navigate to the concerned projects, it’s showing “HTTP 404 Not Found” error and in the Admin console, projects are in Active status.

Ex: Project name: Análysis

Please advise me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First please make sure if all of your mates in teams that fail like this.

Then  double check if you can connect to other normal project in the same project collection smoothly expect the concerned projects with name such as Análysis.

If both of the answer above is *yes*, it's basically confirm that the project name  causing the issue. You can change the name to the normal English character and try the connection again. Suggest you to use normal English character in the project name.

Moreover, here is the **[Naming restrictions and conventions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/naming-restrictions)** in TFS  for your reference.

Comment: Yes, we can able to connect all other projects in that collection smoothly. Can you please tell me, how I can change/rename the team projects in TFS 2013.5.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your TFS version. [Rename a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/rename-team-project) this can only achieved by VSTS or TFS2015 and later. For TFS 2013.5 I'm afraid you have to create a new team project and move code there.

Comment: Is there any other ways to resolve the error, please?

Comment: Renaming project in TFS2013 can't be achieved. [How can I rename a team project and area paths in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344295/how-can-i-rename-a-team-project-and-area-paths-in-tfs) Another way maybe **update your VS** to the latest version. It works well with the same project name `Análysis` on my *VS2015Update3*

Answer (score 0):

You need to 
1. login to the TFS application tier
2. Open IIS and choose sites
3. Select TFS and choose Request Filtering
4. Edit feature settings and click on "Allow high-bit characters"
5. Reset IIS

Thanks